# Remove all password salts from customer table Magento 2

Tags: database, magento2.2, password

I recently did a Cart2Cart migration for customers and customer passwords, but since we have launched, our customers have been having huge trouble logging in!

I've done some research but couldn't find anything and it's come to my attention that the new users created **do not have password salts**, so I'm just wondering how I can directly remove password_salts from the database, and what table these are stored in?

Does anyone have an SQL query that will remove them from the database for Magento 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just remove a salt from a password. The Hash is not working without the salt for the password.

I dont know the exact circumstances why there is no salt (or it looks like there is no salt), but when setting a new Password works the solution is, to require all old users to reset their passwords.
This is not so uncommon for a bigger migration, to require users to get a new Password.